# How to concatenate two select queries output into one column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this query:

```
SELECT s1 || s2 AS fullname, (
    SELECT SUBSTR('MarKJones',1,INSTR(translate('MarkJones', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ),'X',2)-1) 
    FROM dual
) AS s1, (
    SELECT SUBSTR('MarkJones',INSTR(translate('MarkJones', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ),'X',2)) 
    FROM dual
) AS s2,
FROM dual;
```

This query is not working. I need to combine the output of both select queries as "Mark Jones". Kindly help resolve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: spurious comma -> `AS s2,`

Comment: @Ben - Alex K pointed to the spurious **comma**, not the keyword `as`.

Comment: @Ben - that was aliasing a column, not a table/sub-select.

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Comment: @Sparkle_Doable - So, did any of the answers help? This question keeps showing up on my "unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s1 || ' ' || s2 as fullname, s1, s2
  from (
        select
               (select SUBSTR('MarkJones',1,INSTR(translate('MarkJones', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ),'X',2)-1) from dual) as s1,
               (select SUBSTR('MarkJones',INSTR(translate('MarkJones', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ),'X',2)) from dual) as s2
          from dual
       );
```

Column aliases are not available to the same request, only the outher query.

In general, your problem is solved so:

```
select regexp_replace('MarkJones','([A-Z])',' \1',2,1,'c') as fullname,
       regexp_substr('MarkJones','^[A-Z][a-z]+',1,1,'c') as s1,
       regexp_substr('MarkJones','[A-Z][a-z]+',2,1,'c') as s2
  from DUAL
```

Comment: Why does this need a sub-select?

Comment: Why can't you select both s1 and s2 in a single subquery? No need for three levels of select.

Comment: ... and should there be a space between s1 and s2?

Comment: @mathguy I suggested that instead of DUAL in the sub-queries actually something else. Therefore, I leave as is

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

```
select s1 || ' ' || s2 as fullname, s1, s2
  from ( select SUBSTR('DebashisBhadra',1,
                INSTR(translate('DebashisBhadra', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                      'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ),'X',2)-1) as s1,
                SUBSTR('DebashisBhadra',
                INSTR(translate('DebashisBhadra', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ',
                                      'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ),'X',2))   as s2
          from dual
       );

FULLNAME        S1       S2   
--------------- -------- ------
Debashis Bhadra Debashis Bhadra
```

The variant below may be less efficient, but probably easier to read, write, and maintain.

```
with names ( str ) as ( select 'DebashisBhadra' from dual )
select s1 || ' ' || s2, s1, s2 
from (
      select substr(str, 1, regexp_instr(str, '[A-Z]', 2) - 1) as s1, 
             substr(str, regexp_instr(str, '[A-Z]', 2) )       as s2
        from names
);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have the `from` in the wrong place:

```
SELECT s1.x || s2.x AS fullname
FROM (SELECT SUBSTR('DebashisBhadra', 1, INSTR(translate('DebashisBhadra', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ), 'X' , 2)-1) as x
      FROM dual
     ) s1 CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT SUBSTR('DebashisBhadra', INSTR(translate('DebashisBhadra', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' ), 'X', 2)) as x
      FROM dual
     ) s2
FROM dual;
```

There are simpler ways to express the logic, but this would seem to be intent of the method that you are using.

Comment: Thank you for the response.